# Custom route with optional tokens

Tags: routes

I have a question about custom routes set in `routes.php`. Can route segment be optional?

Taking example from docs - `'blog/archive/<year:\d{4}>' => 'controller/action/path'`, can we make year token optional in url and still match route when someone vists `blog/archive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and sweet... I think you just need to add a second route.

```php
'blog/archive' => 'controller/action/path',
'blog/archive/<year:\d{4}>' => 'controller/action/path'
```